# FCM Web Push Notification (Chrome) ONLY for Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new in web developing and is unfamiliar with lots of stuff. So I have been trying to implement push-notification for website Google Chrome. At first I implemented push notification from GCM (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en).

After that, i switch to FCM and imported GCM project into the FCM console. It works just fine and the push notification is still shown as usual at localhost.

I have read the FCM documentation from the FCM Website but still facing lots of trouble understanding it.

From what I have known about FCM push notification

- Free features for notification and it can take unlimited user
- Firebase Database has limited space and required to be purchased

For the back-end, we can choose to

a) create our own app server with condition specified and required to be connected to FCM Connection Server

or

b)Another way is to use FCM service itself and use the FCM connection server to directly handing the client registration IDs and new subscribers.

My 1st question is:

If we manage to connect our own app server with FCM Connection Server, we can have unlimited subscribers. But since it is connected to FCM Connection Server, wouldn't the subscribers be inputed to FCM Database? So technically we can have unlimited subscribers but if the FCM Database has limitation and unable to store everything. We would still have to pay for the features in the end.. Is that right or we create own database ? Also, if we create our own app server, are we still required to install Javascript SDK from FCM?

---

2nd Question:

Once I have created the push service (Front-end) from GCM, are the only remaining steps I have to do is to create a back-end server and implement the Push Api from https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http considered that I will be creating my own app server. Do we still need to implement Firebase Hosting, Database or Storage etc etc?

Thank you for taking your time to read and I am very confused with the current FCM push notification. (/ps: I do not have back-end experience so i may miss out some important stuff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> FCM and Firebase RealTime Database are two different products out of a group of products under same header tagname "Firebase".

Anwser to first question:

- Details of subscribers Using FCM are not added to firebase database. So your database quota is not affected at all if you are only using FCM.
- To save subscriber details, you have to manually implement routine to store user data in  firebase database.
- To use any firebase services you need firebase SDK. [Add Firebase to your JavaScript Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Anwser to second question:

- To Use FCM you don't need to implement Firebase Hosting, Firebase Realtime Database, Firebase Storage or any other Firebase product. Surely, you will need Firebase SDK.

Comment: Thank you.. Cleared some of my misunderstanding. Upvoted it

Comment: @James Lee you missed upvoting. If this works , you can upvote and accept the answer.  Thanks.